# Javascript (error recognition for data type strings), match word that should be inside the quotes

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

Hi, I'm trying to create a javascript code editor, I assume that you know that how string data types are created in javascript, so i want every word inside the symbol (") "double quotes" or (') 'single quotes' into the i html tag. 
 so i made a chaos situation and try to match some words that should be inside the quotes like my expectations.
this is my string string :

```
`that's "that's" 'that's'. Hanna "loves" 'ice "cream`
```

expect output like this:

```
that's <i>that's</i> <i>that's</i>. Hanna <i>loves</i> ice cream
```

```js
let str_ = `that's "that's" 'that's'. Hanna "loves" 'ice "cream`;
// expected output :
// that's <i>that's</i> <i>that's</i>. Hanna <i>loves</i> ice cream
```

Comment: How are you telling the difference between a `'` for italics and `'` for grammar (e.g. `that's`)?

Comment: `I have seen the answers on similar problems but it doesn't work` what is an example of such answers here on SO and why didn't they work for you?

Comment: @evolutionxbox it's just a possible error state. you can change the word to doesn't

Comment: But why should `'s "that'` not be a string? But `'test'` is a valid one. And why should the value for `'that's'`  be `that's` and not just `that`?

Comment: @t.niese that's the problem i got. how to get the output as i expect in such condition.

Comment: In the shown text there is no rule and this is ambiguous. You can't determine for that text whether the quote is part of the text or is for quoting of the string. That's why you won't see such a construct in a programming language. In JavaScript you can have `let str ="something ' something ' something";` or `let str ='something " something " something';`, but  `let str ='that's something';` is not valid JavaScript.

Comment: Exactly. Your input and output examples cannot be transformed by logic that relies on quote characters alone.  You could extend that logic for example with rule saying that »quote character surrounded by alphanumeric characters should be ignored and transferred to the outptut verbatim«, but without precise description you cannot get reliable solution.

Comment: You can do best guesses but not create a reliable parser for such strings. Except if you define very clear constraints on them, but even then it can be problematic. That's why programming languages use escape sequences. If you want to use a `"` within a string quotes with `"` you need to escape it with an ``\``. That's e.g. one reason why parsing natural languages like English are so problematic.

Comment: this is for error recognition function at my code editor. so i made a chaos situation and make sure my app can handle it. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An approach which takes from the OP's example for granted that the beginning and the end of a valid quotation is always accompanied by at least one leading and at least one trailing space might come up with a regex like this [`/(?<space>\s+)(?<quote>['"])(?<text>\S+)\2/gm`](https://regex101.com/r/frH2xQ/1). It uses [capturing groups](https://javascript.info/regexp-groups) in its [named form](https://javascript.info/regexp-groups#named-groups). The following regex is identical to the first one, just without the naming ... [`/(\s+)(['"])(\S+)\2/gm`](https://regex101.com/r/frH2xQ/2). It reads like this ...

- 1st Capturing Group `(\s+)`

  - `\s` matches any whitespace character (equivalent to `[\r\n\t\f\v ]`)
  - `+` matches the previous token between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
- 2nd Capturing Group `(['"])`

  - Match a single character present in the list below `['"]`

    - `'"` matches a single character in the list (case sensitive)
- 3rd Capturing Group `(\S+)`

  - `\S` matches any non-whitespace character (equivalent to `[^\r\n\t\f\v ]`)
  - `+` matches the previous token between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
    `\2` matches the same text as most recently matched by the 2nd capturing group
- *Global pattern flags*

  - `g` modifier: global. All matches (don't return after first match)
  - `m` modifier: multi line. Causes `^` and `$` to match the begin/end of each line (not only begin/end of string)

For each match the replacer callback function of [`String.prototype.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) does provide through its arguments the matched/captured data which will be necessary for the returned replacement value. In this case one can access `(match, space, quote, text)` which makes it possible to return `${ space }<i>${ text }</i>` as computed replacement value.

Since this replacement does not sanitize any crippled/invalid quotes one has to go after them with an extra replacement (based on [`/(\s+)(['"])/gm`](https://regex101.com/r/frH2xQ/3/)) as shown with the loggings of the beneath example code.

```js
// // [https://regex101.com/r/frH2xQ/1] 
// const regXSpacedAndQuotedChars = (/(?<space>\s+)(?<quote>['"])(?<text>\S+)\2/gm);

// [https://regex101.com/r/frH2xQ/2] 
const regXSpacedAndQuotedChars = (/(\s+)(['"])(\S+)\2/gm);

// [https://regex101.com/r/frH2xQ/3/]
const regXSpacedAndSoleQuote = (/(\s+)(['"])/gm);

console.log(
  `that's "that's" 'that's'. Hanna "loves" 'ice "cream`
    .replace(regXSpacedAndQuotedChars, (match, space, quote, text) => `${ space }<i>${ text }</i>`)
);

console.log(
  `that's "that's" 'that's'. Hanna "loves" 'ice "cream`
    .replace(regXSpacedAndQuotedChars, (match, space, quote, text) => `${ space }<i>${ text }</i>`)
    .replace(regXSpacedAndSoleQuote, (match, space, quote) => space)
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I agree that this will work for the shown cases. But given the text in the question `I'm trying to create a javascript code editor,` I would assume that this will fail in practice. It will only work if there are no white spaces between the quotes.

Comment: @t.niese ... This is correct. This was the reason for me upvoting two comments at that matter, yours and the one of *evolutionxbox*, before I started working on the above answer.

Comment: @Peter Seliger this is for error recognition function at my code editor. so i made this chaos situation and make sure my app can handle it. thank you for your solution sir.

Comment: @HannaRose ... 1/2 ... Getting to know regular expression is like getting ones hands on a powerful magic wand. One needs to know the spells (its grammar). But one also needs to know when and especially when not to use it. (Like trying to write parser code entirely based on regex which is like real black magic.)

Comment: @HannaRose ... 2/2 ... Thus on that matter one should follow some good teachers like e.g. [Wiktor Stribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=user%3a3832970%20%5bjavascript%5d%20regex) or [The fourth bird](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A5424988+%5Bjavascript%5D+regex)

Comment: @PeterSeliger yeah i know sir, regex is so important to building my codeeditor. I'm currently focused on learning that. it's quite a lot to remember and I'm not very fluent with it yet. so now i just trying to find the solution in a weird or naif code im not taking care to much hehe as long it works fine. after i found the answer everything will be converted into a regex. thanks for your recomendation sir, i will following them.

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions are indeed powerful and handy, but for "serious business" is it often recommended to use more *robust* approach and avoid regexp for important heavy-lifting (*), i.e. best to implement something like simple **state machine** parser.

As an exercise I tried to make something akin this approach, with rules abstracted from OP's examples, where only "root level, words enclosing quotes" are considered relevant and "dangling" quotes are discarded. So rules are:

- first occurrence of any quote after non-word character enters "quote" state where:

  - other quotes are transferred verbatim,
  - same quotes not followed by non-word character are transferred verbatim
  - same quote followed by non-word character ends quote and exits quote state.
- Opened but unfinished quote is discarded. (This one breaks OP's use case, because there are discarded **all** dangling "nested" quotes, what would IMO massively complicate the state machine. And I've left it to make this case more apparent. Such occurrence is detected and reported in the console.)

For sake of example I've deliberately avoided regexp even for definition of non-word character, which I've kept short (space and `,.!?\/-`, plus quotes `"` and `'` that are handled separately).

Please take this more as an POC: I haven't written any FSM before, so most probably it is not a best learning material.

```js
// @ts-check
function state_machine(input_str) {
  var input_buffer = [...input_str];
  var out = [];
  var char = '';
  var start_quote_adept_index = -1;
  var quote_kind;

  function is_word_char() {
    if (!char) {
      return false;
    }
    if (" ,.!?\\/-".includes(char)) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }

  function is_quote() {
    if (char == "'" || char == '"') {
      return true
    }
    return false
  }

  function add(ch) {
    out.push(ch);
  }
  var states = {
    outside_word: function() {
      if (is_quote()) {
        state = states.in_quote;
        quote_kind = char;
        start_quote_adept_index = i;
        add('');
      } else if (is_word_char()) {
        state = states.in_word
        add(char);
      } else {
        add(char);
      }
    },
    in_quote: function() {
      if (char == quote_kind) {
        state = states.maybe_after_quote;
      } else {
        add(char);
      }
    },
    maybe_after_quote: function() {
      if (is_word_char()) {
        // false alarm: quote inside word
        state = states.in_quote;
        add(quote_kind);
        add(char);
      } else {
        // yup, "proper" quote
        state = states.outside_word;
        out[start_quote_adept_index] = '<i>';
        add('</i>');
        start_quote_adept_index = -1;
        add(char);
      }
    },
    in_word: function() {
      if (is_word_char()) {
        add(char);
      } else {
        state = states.outside_word;
        add(char);
      }
    }
  }

  var state = states.outside_word;
  var i = -1;
  while (++i <= input_buffer.length) {
    //     <= for one extra assignment of `undefined` for finishing state
    char = input_buffer[i];
    state();
  }
  if (start_quote_adept_index > -1) {
    console.warn('Non-balanced quote `%s` at index %s', quote_kind, start_quote_adept_index);
    var err_info = [...input_str];
    err_info.splice(start_quote_adept_index + 1, 0, '%c');
    err_info.splice(start_quote_adept_index, 0, '%c');
    console.info(err_info.join(''), 'border: 1em solid red');
  }
  return out.join('');
}

input.oninput()
```

```html
<input id="input" oninput="console.clear();output.value=state_machine(this.value)" size="80" value="that hat's &quot;that hat's&quot; 'that hat's'. Hanna &quot;loves&quot; '' 'ice &quot;cream">
<br><output id="output" style="white-space: pre-wrap"></output>
```

Notice the handling of the last `"` from initial value violates OP's rules. It is already in "single quote" state (that is unfinished thus discarded, so no `'` get to output) and where double quotes are simply considered as word characters, so `"` slips into output.

OTOH, this approach handles words and even sentences inside quotes without problem.

Core of this approach is in the loop that gradually invokes state function for each character from input string (plus one extra) that checks the character, eventually ads it to the output buffer and sets next state.  For opening quotes it just saves its index and adds `''` to the output until there is matching closing counterpart, then opening tag is inserted to saved index position.  I'm not sure it is best practice, but I think doing it any other way would introduce unnecessary look-arounds. This way it stays in (I think) desirable `O(n)` land.

---

(*) Main advantages of simple FSM over regexp are mainly prevention of various catastrophic backtracking dangers and really difficult readability and 'debugability' of regex literals.

Comment: Thank's for the effort and the detailed explanation

Answer (score 0):

this is my previous solution. but i found the best solution in the 
 Peter Seliger answer. Thank you

```js
function isValidQuotes(word, dir_){
  const wlength = word.length;
  for(let n=0; n<wlength; n++){
    let a = (dir_==='<') ? wlength-n-1 : (dir_==='>') ? n:false;
    if(a === false) return false;
    if( isLetter(word[a]) === false ){
      if( ["'",'"'].indexOf(word[a]) !== -1 ){ return true; }
    }else{
      return false;
    }
  }
}
function isLetter(n) {
  return (n.match(/[A-Za-z0-9]/i) !== null && n !== ' ') ?true:false;
}

let str_ = `that's "that's" 'that's'. Hanna "loves" 'ice "cream`;
// expected output :
// that's <i>that's</i> <i>that's</i>. Hanna <i>loves</i> ice cream
let res = "";
for( let a of str_.split(" ") ){
  if( 
  isValidQuotes(a, '>') === true && isValidQuotes(a, '<') === true
  ){
    res += '<b>'+ a +'</b> ';
  }else{
    res += a+' ';
  }
}
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score -1):

It's not what you want but it makes sense https://regex101.com/r/PdsWVL/2.
Basically, go through the string and find the first occurrence of either a " or a ' and then continue until you find a closing one, then repeat from that position.

Comment: `go through the string and find the first occurrence of either a " or a ' and then continue until you find a closing` the op wants to convert `'that's'` to `<i>that's</i>.` so how do you determine that the `'` in front of the `s` is not the closing one?